# Кнопка назад в приложении

Tags: java, android

Решил добавить кнопку "Назад" в своём приложении.
Прописал всё согласно [офф.документации](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html).

Код `AndroidManifest`:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_map_details"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="ru.topjunior.sai.activities.MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
```

Только хочу чтоб она возвращала не к активити а к фрагменту моему.

Comment: android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"> вроде достаточно те только в манифесте прописать

Comment: И всё таки в ошибке сказано о превышении предела методов. А примеры с навигацией обычно не работают. Попробуйте для начала просто finish вызвать

Comment: @ВладимирСалеев да, всё верно, этого оказалось достаточно, не пойму только почему в офф.документации контент не обновят. Но всё таки вопрос как возращаться к фрагменту моего приложения остаётся открытым)

Comment: Не знаю, если только возвращаться к активности, а не на фрагмент ну и можно посмотреть про стек (*возвращений*/фрагментов/активностей)

Answer (score 2):

> Только хочу чтоб она возвращала не к активити а к фрагменту моему.

Если Вы думаете, что для *возвращения к фрагменту* нужно что-то где-то дописать, то Вы не правы, такого нет.

Допустим у Вас есть некоторый фрагмент, одновременно с этим у Вас должна быть активити, которая является хостом для данного фрагмента, так вот, чтобы *вернутся к этому фрагменту*, Вам просто нужно вернутся к активити, которая выступает хостом для данного фрагмента.

Comment: да, к сожелению я такого не нашёл, но что вы скажете насчёт альтернативы стек фрагментов. Вместо активити использовать фрагмент, тогда если у нас в активити вложен фрагмент A, а в нём еще один B, то мы ведь сможем осуществить переход из фрагмента B во фрагмент A?

Comment: @Morozov, Можно так. Только, наверное, не один фрагмент вложен в другой, а оба фрагмента вложены в активити. В таком случае Вы можете вернутся из одного фрагмента в другой.